# Recurrence relation for the number of partitions of an integer  with distinct summands

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions

Let $Q(n)$ give the number of ways of writing the integer $n$ as a sum of positive integers without regard to order with the constraint that all integers in a given partition are distinct. Equation $(11)$ on [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html) mentions (without proof) a recurrence relation for $Q(n)$,

$$Q(n) = s(n) + 2\sum_{k=1}^\sqrt{n}(-1)^{k+1}Q(n-k^2)$$

where

$$s(n) = \begin{cases}
    (-1)^j,& \text{if } n= j(3j \pm 1)/2\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

I also came across this identity (again no proof) in [Abramowitz and Stegun's book](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/abramowitz_and_stegun.pdf) on mathematical formulas (pg. 826). What is the proof of this fact?

Comment: You asked the same question MSE in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3498499/recurrence-relation-for-the-number-of-partitions-of-an-integer-n-with-distinct Perhaps you want to decide for one site, since then there will be no duplicate answers.

Comment: @EFinat-S I apologize. I had originally intended to post on MSE but there was no activity there. I had heard of MO being for research level math but never posted here . Since this question seemed to fit the guidelines, this became my first post on this site. I was unfortunately not aware of the protocol for migrating questions between MSE and MO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Gauss showed that
  $$ \prod_{n\geq 1}\frac{1-q^n}{1+q^n} = 1+2\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n q^{n^2}. $$
We also have $\sum_{n\geq 0} Q(n)q^n = (1+q)(1+q^2)\cdots$ and $\sum_{n\geq 0} s(n)q^n = (1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots$ (Euler's pentagonal number formula). The recurrence follows from equating coefficients of $q^n$ on both sides of 
  $$ \prod_{n\geq 1}(1-q^n) = \left(1+2\sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n q^{n^2}\right)\prod_{n\geq 1}(1+q^n). $$

Comment: Could you include a reference for the first identity you wrote?

Comment: See Gauss's proof at https://books.google.com/books?id=uDMAAAAAQAAJ, page. 447, equation (14).

Comment: A proof of Gauss' identity also appears in http://www.personal.psu.edu/gea1/pdf/48.pdf.

Answer (score 5):

Richard Stanley already aswered your question about the proof of the identity. But, if you are looking for references, this two articles prove similar (equivalent?) identities:

Ewell, John A., [*Recurrences for two restricted partition functions*](https://www.fq.math.ca/18-1.html),
Fibonacci Quart. 18 (1980), no. 1, 1–2.

Ono, Ken; Robbins, Neville; Wilson, Brad, [*Some recurrences for arithmetical functions*](https://uva.theopenscholar.com/ken-ono/publications?page=8),
J. Indian Math. Soc. (N.S.) 62 (1996), no. 1-4, 29–50.